# JsonPath Conditions from another array | JMETER

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath, json-path-expression

Using JSONPath I'm trying to fetch *pools > id > options > id*

**based on this condition:**
componentGroups > id > poolId = pools > id
"poolId": "cb720883-04f1-4be4-a416-2f0c75230768", = "id": "cb720883-04f1-4be4-a416-2f0c75230768",

I mean one of those IDs from the payload below:

**Example 1:**
for "poolId": "cb720883-04f1-4be4-a416-2f0c75230768", pools > id should be:

"id": "355548b5-b032-44f5-bf91-acfe987be3aa",

"id": "178709f3-f47d-4a6f-9aa1-f27958c628ea",

"id": "b0a227b0-2bf8-47cc-8422-5114edfb5c41",

"id": "ee8e2b49-7539-4ddd-90a4-6745b1385733",

**Example 2:**
for "poolId": "fc2ab5c-c709-4b1d-81a7-e61a8d120d8d", pools > id should be:

"id": "cf85f8ca-7686-4585-b154-2e069e7bf976",

"id": "b0f6c744-af0a-4395-a2d5-bfaf39aeeab5",

**the JSON extractor I use:**

$.data[?(@.productId=='1231a29f0c3-9180-4cd7-a5c7-282f6689c31a')].pools.*.options[?(@.componentGroups.*.poolId = .pools.*.id)].id

```
{
"error": null,
"data": [
    {
        "id": "d8af6a50-1bf4-4792-97ea-f9c819c60f8e",
        "productId": "1231a29f0c3-9180-4cd7-a5c7-282f6689c31a",
        "productName": "Acme One Hundred Percent",
        "pools": [
            {
                "id": "cb720883-04f1-4be4-a416-2f0c75230768",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "355548b5-b032-44f5-bf91-acfe987be3aa",
                        "optionAmount": 1,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "$1",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123./1-dollar-ball.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "178709f3-f47d-4a6f-9aa1-f27958c628ea",
                        "optionAmount": 5,
                        "optionIndex": 1,
                        "optionName": "$5",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/5-dollar-ball.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "b0a227b0-2bf8-47cc-8422-5114edfb5c41",
                        "optionAmount": 10,
                        "optionIndex": 2,
                        "optionName": "$10",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/10-dollar-ball.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "ee8e2b49-7539-4ddd-90a4-6745b1385733",
                        "optionAmount": 20,
                        "optionIndex": 3,
                        "optionName": "$20",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/20-dollar-ball.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Panel Amounts",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "2f1403cb-df3e-4fbf-b594-352f76943895",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "a5dc21e7-cc4e-4e93-b74f-1f4b19f322ef",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "Heads",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/OneHundredPercent/LibertyBellCoin.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Heads",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ],
        "componentGroups": [
            {
                "id": "126140ac-1cfa-40a3-9ab7-1a84469ab0db",
                "poolId": "cb720883-04f1-4be4-a416-2f0c75230768",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "8291365c-df9f-4d7b-8f34-be0b500065ee",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,
                        "componentName": "Panel Amount",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Panel Amount Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "03ed0e60-8fba-4e01-83c2-ce960bf5e889",
                "poolId": "2f1403cb-df3e-4fbf-b594-352f76943895",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "3f4b1a61-5d80-4b78-8c20-9f2b92022cf4",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 1,
                        "componentName": "Heads",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Heads Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "b203c9bc-1a7e-4fe5-9b5b-d8021ea118c6",
        "productId": "123557a97a5-ef93-46b7-868c-4f26439fbcb9",
        "productName": "Acme Pick 3",
        "pools": [
            {
                "id": "efc2ab5c-c709-4b1d-81a7-e61a8d120d8d",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "cf85f8ca-7686-4585-b154-2e069e7bf976",
                        "optionAmount": 0.5,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "$.50",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/01.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "b0f6c744-af0a-4395-a2d5-bfaf39aeeab5",
                        "optionAmount": 1,
                        "optionIndex": 1,
                        "optionName": "$1",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/01.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Panel Amounts",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "60b8910b-baa7-4776-bb7a-05f277887a11",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "d51485a5-1cb4-4aca-8ad9-551ac0bddce3",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "Exact Order",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilestraight.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "4ed3eaa0-7b58-47db-8072-bbe78f0e40cf",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 1,
                        "optionName": "Any Order",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilebox.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "46571384-8bea-404b-8aa1-c0965fa0bed1",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 2,
                        "optionName": "50/50",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilefiftyfifty.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "325d52e8-ed3f-4a69-8f09-8e49a53608dd",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 3,
                        "optionName": "Front Pair",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilefrontpair.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "5960a4af-0b74-4c2b-b8a4-2dc4033e96a2",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 4,
                        "optionName": "Split Pair",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilesplitpair.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "c2a817ca-1bd8-4b5b-8f6f-e12f3286ea54",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 5,
                        "optionName": "Back Pair",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilebackpair.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Play Types",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "53fb7c9a-17dd-4f95-94b0-0110433404a2",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "fae5912c-9d4a-466b-b515-d60b3186c2e5",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "0",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen00.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "42055e6a-f08a-48b4-a7c8-41b87f11ca51",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 1,
                        "optionName": "1",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen01.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "ea28a99c-6068-4d67-8e2d-c6857656b499",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 2,
                        "optionName": "2",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen02.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "bf5e29ea-a377-46ad-865d-e4585d652b13",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 3,
                        "optionName": "3",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen03.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "41c26a4b-ce86-4c28-ae5a-35c13a539fbc",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 4,
                        "optionName": "4",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen04.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "fcb34895-25b9-4e5e-8a00-652febfcd31e",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 5,
                        "optionName": "5",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen05.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0f0cf6ef-a7b7-4d11-98c4-0ea2cfd32f39",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 6,
                        "optionName": "6",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen06.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3db2fafd-698c-44bb-a4be-f9e43ee6248b",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 7,
                        "optionName": "7",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen07.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "25d17003-9db8-407b-b6e2-65c0c2f014a0",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 8,
                        "optionName": "8",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen08.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "37232037-ca87-4f2e-99a4-40cbfec2bf62",
                        "optionAmount": 0,
                        "optionIndex": 9,
                        "optionName": "9",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/tilegreen09.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Numbers",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ],
        "componentGroups": [
            {
                "id": "85ee94f1-fbcf-4392-aa08-5320abc13dcc",
                "poolId": "efc2ab5c-c709-4b1d-81a7-e61a8d120d8d",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "a3d14456-64cb-4cae-b749-133c4b6a476a",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,
                        "componentName": "Panel Amount",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Panel Amount Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "2be68fe5-2872-4631-b994-bb8e691db233",
                "poolId": "60b8910b-baa7-4776-bb7a-05f277887a11",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "d50aeef2-4821-4247-b712-585a2ba55f81",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,
                        "componentName": "Play Type",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Play Type Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "9b3433e8-48f3-4b37-bccb-e0ed5c55ffe8",
                "poolId": "53fb7c9a-17dd-4f95-94b0-0110433404a2",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "ed6a4930-2558-414d-b47f-a3f95e719f60",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "Front Number",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Front Number Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "6ca0c5d1-0939-4603-9c0f-d6be5171a068",
                "poolId": "53fb7c9a-17dd-4f95-94b0-0110433404a2",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "e0957685-22d8-4827-a3db-a1e2e0b5b76b",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "Middle Number",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Middle Number Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "e2ed942b-98e2-4d91-a500-ab5884acf66f",
                "poolId": "53fb7c9a-17dd-4f95-94b0-0110433404a2",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "98b3c77a-bb25-4a45-a2ca-c90a79c75ecb",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "Back Number",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Back Number Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hard to follow what you want.  Here is my attempt:

$.data[?(@.productId=='1231a29f0c3-9180-4cd7-a5c7-282f6689c31a')].pools.[*]

or, dig futher:

$.data[?(@.productId=='1231a29f0c3-9180-4cd7-a5c7-282f6689c31a')].pools.[*].options[*].id

Make your JSON path in two steps, perhaps.  Two variables.  Building-blocks.

Minor issues:

1. you have "=" instead of "==",  see your "@.componentGroups..poolId = .pools.*.id"
2. careful with your path; you are, at one point, in componentGroups but expecting to be in pools

Comment: --Make your JSON path in two steps, perhaps. Two variables. Building-blocks. 

What do you mean by that? Can you please share an example? 

Sorry if it sounds confusing (I know it is confusing :) basically I need IDs of "pools" from the section where componentGroups..poolId = .pools.*.id 

I hope this makes a bit more sense now
Please check this value: cb720883-04f1-4be4-a416-2f0c75230768

it appears twice

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go for 2 [JSON Extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

1. Get all pool ids for the project you want:

   ```
   $.data[?(@.productId=='1231a29f0c3-9180-4cd7-a5c7-282f6689c31a')].pools.*.id
   ```

   [image]

   it will give you a random pool id as `${pool_id}` JMeter Variable

   [image]
2. Then you will be able to get the ids like:

   ```
   $.data.*.pools.*[?(@.id == '${pool_id}')].options.*.id
   ```

   [image]

   and this way you will get all pool ids:

   [image]

You can see all the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with all their respective values using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) and [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination.

Comment: Thank you so much for the creative idea!
It is good but not exactly what I meant - sorry for the confusion, guys!
I will share the screens below...

Dima - ti ochen KRUT!